# Why my Entity Framework Code First Entities are being detached?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am using the code first (EF5) approach to create my domain classes. I perform a query to pull a Parent record w/ a collection of child's. I need to edit my parent and perform CRUD operations on childs.

The problem that when saving my objects (parent/child) the entities state is Detached thus without putting an extra logic I don't now if the objects where modified, deleted or inserted.

How can I enable EF to keep traking of my entities or not detaching my entities?

Here is my code:

```
public class myDbContext : DbContext
{
    #region ConnectionStrings

    public myDbContext()
        : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDB_my"]].ToString())
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        Database.SetInitializer<myDbContext>(null);

        //this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        //this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
    }

    #endregion

    #region EntityFramework

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Entity Framework Configurations

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        //Load Entity Configurations
        dbomyAnotations.Load(ref modelBuilder);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    #endregion

    #region EntityRegistrations

    //Client
    public DbSet<ClientLocation> ClientLocations { get; set; }

    //Templates
    public DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }

    #endregion
}



namespace App.myTrak.BL
{
    public class Templates
    {
        public static ClientLocation getTemplatesForClientLocation(int clientLocationId)
        {
            ClientLocation entity = null;

            using (myDbContext db = new myDbContext())
            {
                entity = db.ClientLocations
                .Where(c => c.ClientLocationId == clientLocationId)
                .Include(t => t.Templates)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            }

            return entity;
        }

        public static void saveForTemplates(ClientLocation clientLocations)
        {
            int Id = clientLocations.ClientLocationId;

            var db = new myDbContext();

            //Client Location
            db.ClientLocations.Attach(clientLocations);
            db.Entry(clientLocations).State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;
            db.Entry(clientLocations).Property(x => x.ShowPresoldProducts).IsModified = true;

            //App Templates
            foreach (var template in clientLocations.Templates)
            {
                db.Templates.Attach(template);
                db.Entry(template).State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;

                if (template.DeleteDate != null)
                {
                    db.Entry(template).Property(x => x.DeleteUserId).IsModified = true;
                    db.Entry(template).Property(x => x.DeleteDate).IsModified = true;

                    template.DeleteDate = Shared.Common.DateTimeUTC();
                }
                else if (template.TemplateId == 0)
                    db.Entry(template).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
                else
                {
                    //Modified
                    db.Entry(template).Property(x => x.TemplateName).IsModified = true;
                    db.Entry(template).Property(x => x.Description).IsModified = true;
                    db.Entry(template).Property(x => x.AppTypeId).IsModified = true;
                    db.Entry(template).Property(x => x.ModifyUserId).IsModified = true;
                    db.Entry(template).Property(x => x.ModifyDate).IsModified = true;

                    template.ModifyDate = Shared.Common.DateTimeUTC();
                    template.ModifyUserId = CurrentUserId;
                }
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            db.Database.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the code in `saveForTemplates` above your "extra logic" that you use as a workaround? I cannot imagine that the entities are detached before `SaveChanges` because you are calling `Attach` in this method. After calling `getTemplatesForClientLocation` they are detached of course because you are disposing the context with the `using` block, so it's necessary to track the changes manually and then attach and change states in a new context.

Comment: Yes the extra logic is the one on the saveForTemplates. Is there a way to maintain the changes? For example, I don't know when an entity is being modify, (one of the fields), so if the entity have a Key > 0 I will update the entity, but if the entity was not modified, I will be posting an innecesary update to the DB. Thanks!